# How to configure apache2 on ubuntu for django restful services

Tags: django, apache, apache2, django-rest-framework

I have django restful services on my ubuntu server which are running on port 84.

When the request is send, it come through the apache2 server which is running on port 80.

Now let say my server ip is "xx.xx.xx.10" and when i call with this url http://xx.xx.xx.10/user where user is the rest service running on django rest framework on port 84. Then the request should go to my django rest service through apache2 and return the desired output.

I tried by using the below configuration in the apache2 :-

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
     WSGIScriptAlias / /myproject/myapp/test/wsgi.py
     <Directory "/myproject/myapp/test/">        
      <Files "wsgi.py">
        Require all granted
      </Files>
     </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

but this is giving internal error saying that test.settings does not exits.

is this the right way to configure the restful services running on different port on apache server.

Comment: How and why are you deploying the services on port 84? The Django docs have instructions to deploy Django with [Apache mod wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) that you might find useful.

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify a python path? If you don't, import mysite will not work.

```
WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com
```

For more info see: [Django docs modWSGI](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/)

Comment: I tried this, still giving the the "internal error saying that test.settings does not exits"

Comment: Can you post a log or terminal output etc also post any other relevant confs

Comment: I am proxying to manage.py runserver. Is this good for production.

Comment: No. Definitely not. You should refer to the docs and deploy with either mod wsgi on Apache or use gunicorn with Nginx. You can also use Apache and gunicorn. Either way you need a multi worker wsgi server, and runserver will not give you that.

Comment: Thanks pypypy, I will use one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issued by using the below configurations :-

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mydomain 
        ServerAlias *.mydomain
        ProxyRequests off
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:84/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:84/
     </VirtualHost>
```